# WPF : trigger mouseenter on a UIElement that is being overlapped by another UIElement

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent, uielement

When I move a label over a Rectangle, I want the rectangle to trigger a `mouseEnter` event, it is not working because the Label overlaps the Rectangle. I tried with `isHitTestVisible = false`, but then I couldn't move the label. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I used a border because, if I recall correctly, it's the only way it can be done.

WINDOW.RESOURCES

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFE6E6E6"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

GRID

```
<Border BorderBrush="#FF000000" BorderThickness="0,0,3,3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
    <Image Name="x0y0" Source="/Tictactoe;component/image/null-black.png"/>
</Border>
```

I hope I grabbed the right stuff for you. :p

Comment: unfortunately it's not working when I hover with a label over it

Comment: Sorry dude. I thought it might have been useful.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?
`

```
<Grid>
        <Rectangle x:Name="rect" Fill="{Binding ElementName=label, Path=Background}" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="label" Text="Hover over me" >
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
```

`

Comment: no it's not what I'm trying to do.. I think my question was not clear enough, I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I achieve this kind of effect with my DataGridRow Objects. Maybe it can help.

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="DataGridRow.DragEnter">
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="DragEnterStoryboard">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                                        To="{StaticResource PartEntityDragEnterBackgroundColor}"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.25"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color"
                                        To="{StaticResource PartEntityDragEnterForegroundColor}"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.25"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
```

Comment: this has not worked either.. Somehow the mouseenter event is not being triggered when the mouse is moving a UIElement.

Comment: Are you sure you are using DragEnter instead of MouseEnter?

Comment: Can I see the code for your DragEnter EventTrigger?